# Do you know which book this is?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

A professor wrote that there is a book that takes a historical approach to mathematical logic:

> There is a book I’d think you’d enjoy, that takes a historical
>   approach. Can’t remember what it’s called right now, but I’ll ask
>   around and let you know.

I know it's not very much information but maybe you know?

Comment: I'm afraid that without further information you most likely won't be able to find it. You should ask your professor if he/she forgot about it.

Comment: What have you tried? If you show other users you have done some searching you are more likely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: @Benedict I was looking for a 2nd book in logic so I emailed the author Graeme Forbes who kindly responded with a recommendation for something that I would like. I like the historical notes in the "beta book" which has a chapter on math history. I can try and email the community in logic. The background is that I took I university course in logic and I want to "dig deeper" and know more modern logic.

Comment: My sense of humour gets the better of me. I'd be interested to know what you manage to find. Good luck!